# Efficient algorithm for visiting all connected subcomponents of a connected graph

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

Starting from a graph, how to identify all connected subsets? Connected components, i.e., maximal connected subsets, can be found in linear time. For simple graphs, e.g., chains, $1-2-...-N,$ connected subsets can be identified/visited in time $N*(N-1)$, and they are: $\{1\}, \{1,2\},..., \{1,2..., N\}, \{2\}, \{2,3\}, ... \{2,3,...,N\})$. On the other hand, if $V$ is a dense edge structure, the number of connected subsets can be exponential in $V$.

Fortunately, graphs I'm interested in have a lot of articulation points so a solution will generally be generated in polynomial time.

For those who are interested, I'm modeling a problem in protein mass-spectrometry. Starting from a protein (chain of amino acids, with occasional long-distance bonds due to amino acid cross-linking), I'd like to generate a database of all sub-species that may result from partial protein breakup.

Thanks,
Arthur

Comment: For algorithmic questions, the cs stackexchange or even SO might be better places for this question. Eg this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658245/efficiently-find-all-connected-subgraphs

Comment: (as an aside, would the fragmentation occur only across peptide bonds and S-S links, or across all backbone bonds? It might make the problem easier if you consider the amino acids as the vertices in your graph, rather than atoms)

Comment: Oh, and for some approaches from chemistry : http://www.dalkescientific.com/writings/diary/archive/2011/01/10/subgraph_enumeration.html

Comment: I think that Breadth First Search or Depth First Search will do it. Both are $\mathcal O(n+m)$ where $n,m$ are the number of vertices and edges respectively. You should also consider space effectiveness, which for this probably means you should use an adjacency *list* (not matrix!). Take these algorithms as a base perhaps, and optimize for your situation.

Comment: This question has been [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658245/efficiently-find-all-connected-subgraphs)